# Automatic TS type from object

Tags: typescript

I have a code like this:

```
import { ApolloClient } from '@apollo/client';

type F = typeof FeaturesManager.features.warrants

export class FeaturesManager {
  static features = {
    warrants: Symbol('WARRANTS'),
  };

  client: ApolloClient<{}>;

  constructor({ client }: { client: ApolloClient<{}> }) {
    this.client = client;
  }

  getFeatureAvailability(feature: F) {

  }
}

new FeaturesManager(new ApolloClient()).getFeatureAvailability(FeaturesManager.features.warrants)
```

Now when I change `FeaturesManager.features` I also need to change `F`. How to fix this code?

**UPDATE**

[Playgroung](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgQUgGzRAwm4BTAO3gF84AzKCEOAcgAEBDdTAegGNdCYaBuAKD4wAnmDxwAYnAC8cYaIhkJeBjACuUPAGcAsgwIMA5nigA6MsrUbNJgO4MoUPTE0C8AD0iw4HBps1KVdS1dfSMoRD44OE0YFWA2cgsg-xkESKi4OwcnTQAuOABlIRAAIwg0AAoaAHVkACU65AA5ABUCmgBKABp0qIN7RyI8wuKyypoAcXrmts6eqOJ+dI58InzUcswcVZgAHgRiAD4lqLYIAhioVTYYaAqkFa44YnyHzjWUZmx3vYPD546EQysgAFsBrI8iNJvD9+AsBH08DBxEkNMgAG4MYBoBglbHAYQVcyBDT5cSAtLpYh8al8Ah4GwBSzBPSGYwVemMjYYb47CodDomIzI1F4DFYnF43CElEklmhYxmUXWLKDZwdPhAA)

Comment: Does your IDE have a "rename" feature?

Comment: Please provide a plaintext self-contained [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing. Ideally I could paste such code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/W4OA7mm) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean?  *Why* do you need to change `F` when you change `FeaturesManager.features`?  Change it to *what*, specifically?  Can you show examples?

Comment: Added playground. 
I meen when iam should add some feature iam should change like this `FeaturesManager.features = { warrans, garants }`, but `F` not chaged automatically. 
Thank you for your responses

Comment: Are you looking for something like `type F = typeof FeaturesManager.features[keyof typeof FeaturesManager.features]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add all the features, you can use the `keyof` iterator to extract all the keys and use them to index over the type.

For you above example, the code should look like

```js
type F = typeof FeaturesManager.features[keyof typeof FeaturesManager.features]
```

or maybe a cleaner way would be

```js
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
type F = ValueOf<typeof FeaturesManager.features>
```

Another thing I noticed was that you're using symbols which might not be the best because typescript might not be able to recognize the differences. It might be better to use enums or strings for features and you'll get better typescript support.